# Mail sending is failed using java

Tags: java, email

I have used java mail API for sending mail in my application using java and web driver.My requirement is to send a mail whenever a link/url is down.Even though mail is send when i give url incorrectly ,but at the same time if a url is not loading due any other issue (page not found), found that mail is not getting send.

```
public void SendMail(String url,String str)
{        
    try
    {

        Sheet mailsheet = w.getSheet("mail");            
        String from = mailsheet.getCell(0,1).getContents().toString().trim();      
        String  toEmailID=mailsheet.getCell(1,1).getContents().toString().trim();   
        Properties props = new Properties();     
        String mailprotocol = mailsheet.getCell(2,1).getContents().toString().trim();   
        String mailprotocoltype = mailsheet.getCell(3,1).getContents().toString().trim();   
        String mailhost = mailsheet.getCell(4,1).getContents().toString().trim();   
        String mailhostip = mailsheet.getCell(5,1).getContents().toString().trim(); 
        String mailport=mailsheet.getCell(6,1).getContents().toString().trim(); 
        String mailportid=mailsheet.getCell(7,1).getContents().toString().trim();
        props.put(mailprotocol,mailprotocoltype);
        props.put(mailhost,mailhostip);
        props.put(mailport,mailportid);
        javax.mail.Session mailSession =javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(toEmailID));          
        msg.setSubject("Test Summary");       
        msg.setContent("<html><body>Dear Admin,<br> Website page  "+ "<b><i>"+url + "</b></i>"+" cannot be loaded due to the following :<br> <br></body></html>"+str,"text/html");
        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("Mail is successfully sent to Recipient address with Error information.");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("Mail cannot be send to Recipient address due to connection error");
    } 
}

public void x() {
    SendMail(url,driver.getTitle());    
}
```

Comment: how does it fail? Are you running into the exception, or is it just not send? Frst thought would be, that the try block is interrupted before the mail was send

Comment: i did not get any exception.it just not getting send.Also SOP is getting printed that mail is send to recipient address

Comment: This could be anything. You have lots of `mailsheet.getCell(7,1)` ...so put a breakpoint in there, debug it, see what values **each** property is getting, and make sure it is correct. Who's the email provider? If it's internal, check the logs on the email server to see if the email request is sent. This is also a poor test. The page could be 'down' for many reasons, you should **define** what exactly 'down' means and nonetheless there are many free services out there doing **exactly** this.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Selenium or WebDriver (Which has no support and is nothing to do with sending email).  There is virtually no Selenium/WebDriver in the code snippet you supplied.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably in the bit of code you don't show us : the part where you test the URL.
The response code for a wrong domain name is different from the response code due to a page not found. Also, depending on the system you're targetting, it's possible that page not found are redirected to the index page, making detection even more difficult.

Comment: i am calling the method driver.get(url); to fetch the page

Comment: and what are you testing then ? Also, from your updated code, it seems logic that if driver.get() fails, driver.getTitle() won't be of help neither.